# F# Function using mutually recursive auxiliary functions

Tags: f#

```
 type Title    = string
 type Document = Title * Element list
 and  Element  = Par of string | Sec of Document;;

 let s1   = ("Background", [Par "Bla"])
 let s21  = ("Expressions", [Sec("Arithmetical Expressions", [Par "Bla"]);
                             Sec("Boolean Expressions", [Par "Bla"])])
 let s222 = ("Switch statements", [Par "Bla"])
 let s223 = ("Repeat statements", [Par "Bla"])
 let s22  = ("Statements",[Sec("Basics", [Par "Bla"]) ; Sec s222; Sec s223])
 let s23  = ("Programs", [Par "Bla"])
 let s2   = ("The Programming Language", [Sec s21; Sec s22; Sec s23])
 let s3   = ("Tasks", [Sec("Frontend", [Par "Bla"]);
                       Sec("Backend", [Par "Bla"])])
 let doc  = ("Compiler project", [Par "Bla"; Sec s1; Sec s2; Sec s3]);;
```

Define an F# function `toc: Document → ToC` that generates the table of contents for the document. For Example, the document should have prefixes with numbered subheadings like the one below:

```
[([], "Compiler project");
     ([1], "Background");
     ([2], "The Programming Language");
     ([2;1], "Expressions");
     ([2;1;1], "Arithmetical Expressions");
     ([2;1;2], "Boolean Expressions");
     ([2;2], "Statements");
     ([2;2;1], "Basics");
     ([2;2;2], "Switch statements");
     ([2;2;3], "Repeat statements");
     ([2;3], "Programs");
     ([3], "Tasks");
     ([3;1], "Frontend");
     ([3;2], "Backend")]
```

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried so far?  Is this homework?

Comment: It isnt hw, and weve tried many things so far. We were seeing if we could use previously made functions to help us implement this one. Like this one to try and count the number of sections in the document:

Comment: let rec noOfSecs (d:Document) : int = 
    match d with
    | (t, es) when List.isEmpty es  -> 0
    | (t, es) -> countSec es
and countSec (e:Element list) :int =
    match e with
    | Sec(t,es)::xs -> 1 + countSec es + countSec xs
    | Par t::xs -> countSec xs
    | [] -> 0

noOfSecs doc

Comment: and this one to print the titles of each section: let rec titlesInDoc (d:Document) :Title list =
    match d with
    | (t,es) when List.isEmpty es -> []
    | (t,es) -> addToList es
and addToList (e:Element list) :Title list =
    match e with
    | Sec(t,es)::xs -> t::addToList es @ addToList xs
    | Par t::xs -> addToList xs
    | [] -> []

titlesInDoc ("Compiler project", [Par "Bla"; Sec s1; Sec s2; Sec s3])
let test = titlesInDoc doc

Comment: I just need to implement a function so that the output has the title of each section and also the section number. E.g. Repeat Statements should have the section number 2;2;3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this relatively easily by iterating over the sections in a sequence expression, keeping the number of the current section and yielding all the titles with the current section number.

```
// Given the current level (as a list of numbers) and a list of elements, 
// generate a list of headings in the elements and prepend `idx` indices
// to each heading that we generate
let rec generateToc idx elems = seq {

  // We only care about nested sections, so this gets a list containing
  // just sections and we later add number to them using `Seq.indexed`
  let nested = elems |> Seq.choose (function 
    | Sec(title, elems) -> Some(title, elems) | _ -> None) 

  // For every nested section, we yield the title of the section and then
  // recursively call `generateToc` to get the nested section titles
  // (we append the current section number to `idx` when making the recursive call)
  for i, (title, elems) in Seq.indexed nested do
    yield List.rev (i+1::idx), title
    yield! generateToc (i+1::idx) elems }

// To generate document TOC, we just yield the document title and
// then call `generateToc` on the document elements
let generateDocToc (title, elems) = seq {
  yield [], title
  yield! generateToc [] elems }

generateDocToc  doc
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing quite a bit from your question.  For example: what mutually recursive auxiliary functions do you imagine would be helpful for doing this?

To me it looks like this should be quite straightforward as just a single recursive function.  The basic logic could be:

1. For each element, if it's a paragraph ignore it, or if it's a subsection then generate the corresponding TOC.
2. Append a new index (one per subsection, starting with 1) to all of the entries in each subsection.
3. Add `[],title` to the beginning of this TOC.